# How to uninstall synaptik touchpad (or configure it to use natural scrolling)

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-center, touchpad

I installed synaptiks touchpad recently from http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/synaptiks/kde-config-touchpad_0.8.1-2_all.deb

However, it doesn't seem to have any real improvements that I noticed over the touchpad "program" (?) that came with Ubuntu Unity, not to mention apparently you can't activate natural scrolling on it. So I want to either uninstall it (preferably), or figure out how to use natural scrolling with it. Now, this is going to sound like a very stupid problem, but I have no clue how I would uninstall it. Normally if I had installed it with `apt` I would just do `apt remove`.

I installed this from the debian file with the Ubuntu `software-center`, however now I can't figure out how to make `software-center` uninstall it again. I doesn't seem to show up on the installed section (unless I'm looking for the wrong thing), not as `synaptiks`, nor as `kde-config-touchpad`. So I'm a bit lost. I can't seem to disable it or remove it.

Running ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Have you tried `sudo dpkg -r kde-config-touchpad_0.8.1-2_all.deb` ?

Comment: The correct command is `sudo dpkg -r kde-config-touchpad`

Comment: Oh I thought I did, but apparently not. It worked, thanks :)